# tikz: tabbing environment in nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabbing

I need to use the tabbing environment in a TikZ node. When I try the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,minimum size=1cm,text width=3cm,
  text centered}]
  
  \node[box] (mybox) at (0.0,0.0) {
    \begin{tabbing}
      abcdef \= abcdef \kill
      hello \> there
    \end{tabbing}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

it results in an empty line before the "hello there":

[image]

How can I get rid of the empty line (other than adding `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the contents that `tikz` has difficulties to handle into a savebox.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\hello
\savebox\hello{%
  \begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \begin{tabbing}
      abcdef \= abcdef \kill
      hello \> there
    \end{tabbing}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]{\usebox\hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]